# How to check number of different characters using regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create regex to find all inputs containing max three different characters. It doesn't matter how long the input is.

Example of cases:

- "32 32 32 32 34" --> match
- "MM" --> match
- "  " --> match
- "1234" --> no match

I've done regex to find inputs of four or more different chars, but now I need it in opposite way...

```
(.).*(?\1)(.).*(?\1)(?\2)(.).*(?\1)(?\2)(?\3)(.)
```

Main question is: How to check number of different characters?

Comment: This seems to me like a very convoluted problem to solve with a regex. Is that a requirement? Why not solve it in a more traditional way?

Comment: Judging by your first example, whitespace doesn't count towards the 3 characters?

Comment: This isn't achievable using formal regular expressions, as you need some kind of stack or count or state, which regular languages can't have. In practice, you might be able to work something about as most regex parsers do not define regular languages, but it's best to use a different method.

Comment: Agree with the above comments.
    Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I’ll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.
— Jamie Zawinski

Comment: @Oliver this is certainly something achievable with backreferences, which are present in pretty much any regex engine out there. I'm even thinking on a finite alphabet, this should actually be a regular language (backreferences just make the solution neater). anyway, not using regular expressions would make things a lot easier, I agree.

Comment: [Proof Of Concept](http://regex101.com/r/zQ2tL5), you have to define **different characters** in groups.

Comment: Given that you have the opposite expression already, just test it and negate the result. E.g. `threeorless = !regex.match(fourormore)`.

Answer (score 4):

The following will match a string with a maximum of three different non-space characters

```
^\s*(\S)?(?:\s|\1)*(\S)?(?:\s|\1|\2)*(\S)?(?:\s|\1|\2|\3)*$
```

`(\S)` matches one non-space character and captures it so it can then be referenced later in the regex using a back-reference e.g. `\1`. The `?` in the `(\S)?` are used so the string can contain zero, one, two or three types of non-space characters.

The `?:` make a group non-capturing.

The first part of the regex captures up to three different non-space characters `\1`, `\2`, `\3`, and then `(?:\s|\1|\2|\3)*` ensures only those characters or space `\s` can then appear before the end of the string `$`.

One way, in Javascript, to count the number of different non-space characters in a string "using regex":

```
var str = 'ABC ABC';
var chars = '';

str.replace( /\S/g,  function ( m ) {
    if ( chars.indexOf(m) == -1 ) chars += m;
});

chars.length;    // 3
```

Comment: Why do you have slashes at the start and end? (Hint: slashes have nothing whatsoever to do with regex. They are an app language artefact)

Comment: @Bohemian It is a common convention, like putting strings in quotation marks or URLs inside angle brackets. No need to be pedantic. There is no confusion.

Comment: @RaymondChen I disagree. It's not common and it's not correct. *Some* languages use slashes, but for example the two languages I'm most familiar with (and which are *very* popular) - Java and SQL - don't use slashes. Novice users may not know about slashes and be confused. This site strives for correctness. The fact is, the answer given is wrong, even if a slash-using language had been established (which it has not), technically it would *still* be incorrect, because the slashes are *not* part of the required *regex*, and this question is about regex.

Comment: Languages that use slash: vi, ed, awk, JavaScript, perl, AQL. Languages that don't use slash: Java, C#, SQL. ["2.Some utilities and most languages use / (forward slash) to start and end (de-limit or contain) the search expression"](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#notes). At any rate, it is unlikely to cause confusion. Even you, totally unfamiliar with the slash convention, were able to figure it out.

Comment: @user2335311. If you're happy with this answer, please accept it by clicking the tick (check mark) on the left under the vote arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Good q. Here's the simplest I could come up:

```
^\s*([^\s]{1,3}\s+)*[^\s]{0,3}$
```

**Explanation:**

1. `^\s*` matches any amount of whitespace at the start.
2. `([^\s]{1,3}\s+)*` matches repeating groups of between one and three
   non-whitespace characters followed by at least one whitespace character. *Consider putting `?:` after `(` to make this a non-capturing group.*
3. The final `[^\s]{0,3}` allows the string to end with up to three non-whitespace characters (so it doesn't have to end with whitespace as enforced by 2.)

**Visualisation:**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Demo:**

Test it here: [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ONw95hhX_t9k_H_q)